# File read progress

Tags: java

I am using java to read a TSV file that is 4gb in size and i wanted to know if there is a way for java to tell me how far it is through the task as the program is running. I'm thinking file stream might be able to tell me how many bytes it has read and i could do some simple math with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plain stream or reader doesn't count the number of bytes / characters read.

I think you might be looking for [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html).

If you don't want / need the Swing integration, then another alternative is
to write a custom subclass of FilterReader or FilterInputStream that counts the characters/bytes read and provides a getter for reading the count.  Then put the custom class into your input stack at the appropriate point.

Comment: That's a cool class. Been around for yonks and I've never heard of it. If the OP is using Swing then this is definitely worth looking at.

Answer (score 2):

As you read from the stream, keep a tally of bytes read. For example, if you are reading byte arrays directly from the stream:

```
    long bytesReadTotal = 0L;
    int bytesRead = stream.read(bytes);
    while (bytesRead != -1) {
        bytesReadTotal += bytesRead;
        // process these bytes ...
        bytesRead = stream.read(bytes)
    }
```

Comment: Is that supposed to say 0L or just 0? I don't use the "long" data type much

Comment: They both work, 0L means the value is long type, a single 0 is a integer, and integer can be converted to long.

Answer (score 0):

If you read this file through HTTP, there is a header named "Content-Length" can tell you the total number of bytes you should read, then you know the progress while you are reading.

If you read the file through TCP/UDP, I guess you should write both the client and the server for file transferring, then you should send the file length first to the client, then read the file.

If you just read a local file, this is not a problem.

Comment: File file = new File("path/to/your/local/file");
        long totalBytes = file.length();
        InputStream reader = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int byteRead = -1;
        long byteReadSoFar= 0;
        while (-1 != (byteRead = reader.read(buffer))){
             byteReadSoFar += byteRead;
             System.out.printf("Current progress is: %.2f", byteReadSoFar * 1.0 / totalBytes);
        }  
        reader.close();